# Typescript: Is there way to error out creation of the interface if identical footprint already defined?

Tags: typescript

We have pretty big Angular/Typescript project. Lets say I defined interface like

```js
export interface RangeNumber {
  from: number;
  to: number;
}
```

I would like for typescript or linter to throw error or warning if someone in same project will try to create interface that have **exactly** same property names/types as RangeNumber. For example someone creating:

```js
export interface MyRange {
  from: number;
  to: number;
}
```

Otherwise I have to police developers and make sure they use our generic classes/interfaces instead of reinventing wheel. Is there way?

Comment: I don't understand the use case.  Why does it matter if someone makes their own interface that's structurally identical to `RangeNumber`?  And why is it likely enough for you to worry about prohibiting it?  (That is, how do these developers know they need a type equivalent to `RangeNumber` without knowing about `RangeNumber`?)

Comment: You don't need to police this. That is why static typing exists. If someone is going to completely rewrite this *and* all it's consumers from scratch, that's on them, and points to an issue with project structure.

Comment: Main reson is that developers in general lazy to discover existing types and tend to choose path of least resistance by creating their own version. This policing will force them to think not just about their small part of the project but whole project.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably an external static analysis tool rather than the TypeScript compiler itself.

One example that comes to mind is PMD's copy-paste detector function that enforces the DRY principle in coding: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.23.0/pmd_userdocs_cpd.html

I'm sure there are other similar tools out there. However, I don't think any of them will be close to perfect since detecting similarities like that is a difficult task given how subjective it is.

For example, you can have two interfaces that are identical but named differently because they serve different purposes:

```js
interface Range {
    from: number;
    to: number;
}

interface Coordinate {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
```

In terms of data types, you can swap these two and have the code perform exactly the same way. But there is merit to keeping both of these, one reason being that it would improve the readability of the code and help a developer understand what is happening.

Comment: And much more importantly, making two interfaces, even if they share the exact same property names/types, means you can add or remove parts of one interface without it affecting any of the others, meaning only relevant units will be affected by changes.

Comment: If you must then derive one from another. Imho copy/pasting interfaces falls in the same category as copy/pasting blocks of code instead of extracting them into reusable functions.

Comment: @Aziz my case is for exact copy of names and types. In your example Im trying to avoid Coordinate to have {from: number; to: number;}

Comment: @AndreiV It is not the same at all and that is a gross misunderstanding of what an interface is and does. Interfaces do not exist to reduce the amount you need to type, they exist for enforcing program correctness. If you do what you say there your code will not be cohesive. You are using it as a copy/paste mechanism, which is no better than actually copy/pasting.

Comment: For example, what if you brought in a library that uses an interface with the same names/typings as one that exists in your own code. Would you want to check those too? Of course not. Those interfaces are only relevant to the code that consumes it. It is the same thing.

Comment: @ZombieTfk in original question i was talking about types defined in your project (not brought from outside as library). I completely agree that we have no control of external types. To your other point. Can you give an example where having 2 identical types with different names is beneficial. If you really want it then in my original example you can simply derive MyRange from RangeNumber.

Comment: I dont see any meaningful distinction between code you've written in your project and any you bring in from external libraries, your units should still be as cohesive as possible with clearly defined edges? Intented usage is everything with interfaces. What if you decided to change the field names in one consumer and not another, how are you going to resolve that? What if you need to add a property to the base interface but isnt needed by the one you derive? It just adds coupling between interfaces now for no reason.